# workflow for editing css that was created with less

Tags: css, less

I'm new to pre-prossesors and am still trying to figure out the workflow for editing documents created with less. So say I have a template I downloaded off the internet where the css was created with less. So I have : somefile.less, and somefile.css. Say I go make changes to somefile.css, will that then update the corresponding rules in the less file? or how does that work? Also do I need to install some extras to be able to edit the .less file and have it update the css? lastly at what point are the less rules converted to css? is it when the document is delivered to the browser via http or does it happen locally before launch. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using something like LESS or SCSS you don't edit the CSS directly, the CSS is compiled from your less/scss files.

You can either use command line tools to compile the changes, or an application. For example, I use CodeKit for OSX (not-free) which monitors my folders & files and as soon as I save an SCSS file, the CSS files are compiled and my browser dynamically updates the changes automatically.

There are however loads of free solutions, just look up "[less comiler [your os]](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=less%20compiler%20windows&oq=less%20compiler%20windows&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2726j0&sourceid=chrome&espvd=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8)".

Comment: got it thanks. You can edit the css though too right? like in the scenerio I mentioned. (even if it defeats the purpose). The reason I ask is I'm not entirely comfortable yet editing the less, and say if I have a theme file from themeforest where the styles were created with less, I'm wondering what the impact if any would be on the less if I were to just update the css.

Comment: Of course you can update the CSS directly, but you lose all the advantages of using LESS. Then if you do decide to use LESS in the future then you changes in the CSS file will be overwritten.

Comment: aha, got it. So the less is compiled then in the browser. (ie at load time)?

Comment: It *can* be compiled in the browser using javascript, but you would 99.9% of the time compile it on your machine using a LESS compiler then upload the compiled CSS file. Most of the time you wouldn't even bother uploading the LESS file itself.

Comment: ahh I see. Well thanks for the clarifications on that. Will have to play with it a bit more in my free time. Truth is I'm too comfortable editing my CSS is firebug to give that up for less, but that will probably change soon when it gets less support.